# how to do encoding of opencv float 32 matrix into 3 channels of uint8

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a cv::Mat of type CV_32FC1 and want to encode it to a CV_8UC3 for transmitting it as a image.

My question is then, how can this be done most effecient in with opencv ? ofcause i can manually just loop over all values and do the encoding my self but thinking there must be a smarter way.

The only rule is that I need to be able to convert back from the png or jpg image in javascript (ofcause with some lose of data since its going from 32bit to 24bit.

Here is my attempt to illustrate one way: (it dont compile, >> operator not working, anyone who can make it work?)

```
auto path = msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >(this->context->Payload->InputFile);
cv::Mat dem = cv::imread(path, cv::IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL | cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);
std::cout << "Loading: " << dem.rows << " " << dem.cols << " " << dem.type();

cv::Mat_<int> mat32sc1;
dem.convertTo(mat32sc1, CV_32SC1, 10, 11000);

std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
channels.push_back((mat32sc1 >> 16) & 0xFF);
channels.push_back((mat32sc1 >> 8) & 0xFF);
channels.push_back((mat32sc1 >> 0) & 0xFF);
channels.push_back((mat32sc1 >> 24) & 0xFF);

cv::Mat mat8uc4;
cv::merge(channels, mat8uc4);
```

### Update 2

So here is my final code. Channel 0 should have the first 8 bit worth of value, channel 1 should have next 8 bits. Rest is ignored.

Need to test it ofcause.

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
channels.resize(3);

bitwise_and(mat32sc1, cv::Scalar(255), channels[0]); // is this needed or will converTo truncate automaticly.
channels[0].convertTo(channels[0], CV_8UC1);
mat32sc1.convertTo(channels[1], CV_8UC1, 1.0 / (1 << 8));
channels[2] = cv::Mat::zeros(dem.rows, dem.cols, CV_8UC1);

cv::Mat mat8uc4;
cv::merge(channels, mat8uc4);
```

Comment: CV_8UC1 would be a valid png or jpg format, too. and you could use a single convertTo() call.

Comment: ye, that was my idea. I just need to get the numbers encoded properly. I pasted example code that do not compile due to missing shift operator.